# Meaning of "about" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

> It is very hard to define the meaning of the words as and if.
>
> ***About*** the best that I can do is to give you yet another example: Why should I act as if I cared? = Why should I pretend that I care? I do not care.
>
> If this doesn't help you any, maybe somebody else will be up to the task of explaining to you what as if means.

[Source](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/as-if.3933867/#post-20137859)

---

I'm not sure if "***About***" is an adverb or preposition, and what "***About***" means.

Comment: About = approximately or roughly (adverb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"About" in this context is an adverb here, not  preposition.

"About the best I can do" means its approximately the best I can do.